# What's the tolerance HERE maps API uses for determining the number of returned routes

Tags: here-api

The documentation doesn't specify the tolerance the API uses to determine this number, it only says that the alteratives are not significantly different from the original route in estimated time of arrival.

Comment: Hi, Let me confirm about the api. Which api do you refer in developer.here.com? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, the Routing REST API.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. The API you mentioned is Routing API V8? Would you please tell in detail the issue you met? Do you have any snipped code?

Comment: Yes, I'm using v8. It's not really an issue, I just wanted to know how the API makes this decision (of how many routes to return).

Comment: Is this question about some routing algorithm such as how to determine a best route?

Comment: Not exactly, the API finds the top k fastest route. I want to know how the k is determined

Comment: I am still confused about the K meaning. In Routing V8 there is a param which is routing mode=[fast|short] in https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.9.1/api-reference-swagger.html. Is this you are looking for?

Comment: K is the number of different routes the API returns. There is an alternatives param, that you can set the maximum number of routes returned, but the actual number is "random". I want to know how the API decides this number

Comment: What is the actual number is "random"?

Comment: The alternatives routing is likely to be fastest, shortest, time/distance optimized, recommended, cost based routes calculated by some path finding algorithms.